# pbs jobs and fortran

Tags: fortran, pbs

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

I want to edit *parameters.dat* file that the executable a.out will read and perform calculations on. If I submit a job with ***qsub***, can I modify this same *parameters.dat* file and submit a different job even if the first job is seating in the queue? What can I expect to be the outcome?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, the parameter file will be read at runtime, not at queue time. So if you change it in between, you won't get the results you expect.

One solution is to have a different input file for each job you submit. The easiest is probably to create one directory containing a `parameters.dat` for each job you submit and submit your job to run inside this directory.